# Select info from one mysql db if value exist in another db

Tags: sql, mysql, union

I have this query `select latitude, longitude, username, rank from users`, but I only want that info if the `username` exist in my `online_users` db. That look like this:

```
id bigint(20)           
username varchar(16)
ip varchar(39)
time datetime
```

So if I have 3 users in my `online_users` db, I want the `latitude, longitude, username and rank` from my `users` table from those 3 users. How do I do this? I assume `UNION` something, but my sql skills are limited.

Comment: Are you confusing the idea of a database and a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that these are two tables in the same database, and not two databases (as stated), then either of the following will work:

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, username, rank 
  FROM users INNER JOIN online_users ON users.username = online_users.username

SELECT latitude, longitude, username, rank 
  FROM users WHERE username IN (SELECT username FROM online_users)
```

Comment: EXISTS would work too, but the JOIN is probably the best performing of the three options.

Comment: I was going to ad the EXISTS option, but I usually reserve that for cases in which two or more columns need to be tested and multiple rows might match.  I consider IN the "clearest", but that's purely because I "grew up" using it.  I know MySQL has performance issues with certain IN subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

You'd use an INNER JOIN, rather than a UNION, to ensure you're getting only records with a relationship in another table:

```
SELECT u.latitude, u.longitude, u.username, u.rank 
  FROM USERS u
  JOIN ONLINE_USERS ou ON ou.username = u.username
```

This is a [good introduction to joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

If the tables are in different databases on the same MySQL instance, you prefix the table references with the respective database:

```
SELECT u.latitude, u.longitude, u.username, u.rank 
  FROM DB1.USERS u
  JOIN DB2.ONLINE_USERS ou ON ou.username = u.username
```

The user running the query will need to have access to the tables.